# Duplicate dictionary keys in initialization - Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it correct to say that the rightmost/last key-value pair for a given key would always be considered if there are multiple identical keys when initializing a dictionary ?

Example :

```
Dict = {'A': 5, 'B': 6, 'A': 10}
```

Will `Dict['A']` always be `10` in all python implementations? Where does python enforce this ?

Answer (score 1):

You know that python `dict` can't contain duplicate keys. So

```
Dict = {'A': 5, 'B': 6)
Dict.update({'A': 10})
print(Dict['A'])
```

will result in the last value assigned to the key `A`:

Output:

```
10
```

So the situation is almost like that, python goes through the dictionary during evaluation, and keeps the last value assigned to the keys.

---

I know `dict` aren't ordered, but:

- That doesn't mean python will jump back and forth on the `dict` when parsing the `dict` into memory.
- It will parse through it from left to right to get the collect the data, but it stores the `dict` without keeping its order.

Comment: Thanks! For your last point, probably easier to separate into two points 1) Order of parsing 2) Order of storing in memory.1) is enforced but not 2) in python dictionaries. I think this helps clear that there is no ‘tossing’ of order involved as there was none in the first place.

Comment: Cpython Dicts are ordered in practice from 3.6 and that’s now in the API specs as well since 3.7

Answer (score 1):

Python dict can not have duplicate keys. if you try to add the same key again, it will update the existing key with the new value.

```
Dict = {'A': 5, 'B': 6, 'A': 10}
print(Dict)
{'A': 10, 'B': 6}
```

the above statement execution is similar to below:

```
Dict['A'] = 5    
print(Dict)
{'A'=5}

Dict['B'] = 6 
print(Dict)
{'A'=5, 'B'=6}

Dict['A'] = 10
print(Dict)
{'A'=10, 'B'=6}
```